# Multiple resolutions custom UI strategy

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, user-interface

I made my last iOS apps for iOS4 when I didn't have to worry too much about different scales and resolutions.

I made custom tableview cells with filling multiple `CGRect` programmatically without using Interface Builder. But this doesn't feel like a smart thing to do with 5 or more different sizes (iPhone 4, 5, 6 Plus, iPad, iPad mini ...) and several different resolutions.

Is the Interface Builder worth using and helping me with this problem?

What is your strategy to sanely design custom views in iOS8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Autolayout. Either programmatically or using interface builder. 
Check out the Autolayout videos from WWDC 12 and 13.

Comment: That does look promising. Would it be a hassle to edit an existing layout with this or should I start over?

Comment: You will probably want to rewrite existing layout for the most part. But Autolayout can also coincide with frame defined layout. It does take some time to wrap your head around how to use it. But once you start, you'll never look back :)